# I am unable to edit / delete archive product

Tags: administration, product, archive

I can see it with the direct url ( orgurl/recordId ), but I can't do anything with it: I can't edit or delete this record when I opened this record in salesforce classic display "This record has been archived and is no longer available for any DML operation" I am unable to find to problem please resolve asap.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is at least partially [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336276&type=1) and is subject to an open [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdmq7UAB/ability-to-delete-archived-products) on the IdeaExchange.

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. You cannot perform the operation you are trying to perform. You may wish to create a new Product entry.

Comment: Can we delete this record and I also did n't find this record in developer console. help me

Comment: Did you read the Idea linked above?

Comment: Not exactly understand on Idea linked can you explain to me little bit

Comment: What you want to do is not supported.

Comment: -David Reed I understand the archive product is not deleted because salesforce does not provide the feature to delete this we can create an archive record